# Grafana-Faro - How do you send HTTP requests (and other logs) to Loki

Tags: angular, grafana-loki, grafana-faro

I have the set up below. I know the code below is definitely working -- my grafana calls are going through & I can search for and find my Trace-Ids (from the calls) in Tempo, but I am not getting any logs in Loki. (implemented in Angular)

```
initialize() {
    const FARO_URL = ...;
    const NAME = '...';
    const VERSION = '...';

    initializeFaro({
      url: ...,
      apiKey: '...',
      app: {
        name: ...,
        version: '...',
        environment: 'env',
      },
      instrumentations: [
        new ConsoleInstrumentation({
          disabledLevels: [LogLevel.INFO, LogLevel.LOG, LogLevel.TRACE, LogLevel.DEBUG],
        }),
        new SessionInstrumentation(),
        new WebVitalsInstrumentation(),
      ]
    });

    faro.api.initOTEL(trace, context);

    const resource = Resource.default().merge(
      new Resource({
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_NAME]: NAME,
        [SemanticResourceAttributes.SERVICE_VERSION]: VERSION,
      })
    );

    const provider = new WebTracerProvider({ resource });

    provider.addSpanProcessor(new FaroSessionSpanProcessor(new BatchSpanProcessor(new FaroTraceExporter({ ...faro })), faro.metas));

    provider.register({
      propagator: new W3CTraceContextPropagator(),
      contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
    });

    const ignoreUrls = [FARO_URL];
    registerInstrumentations({
      instrumentations: [
        new XMLHttpRequestInstrumentation({ ignoreUrls }),
        new FetchInstrumentation({ ignoreUrls }),
      ],
    });
  }
```